# How to make a vertically expanding menu in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to make a menu for a website using the asp:menu object. I currently have a vertical menu with one row of parent items and each one reveals a subset of child items when hovered over.

However, the child items appear to the *right* of the parent and I would like them to appear *below* the parent while expanding the *parent menu downwards* so nothing gets covered up. Like a opening a sliding door.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: I'd use jquery, but that's just me.

Comment: Ye, like Kevin said, use jquery. Here's a very easy example to create an accordion menu with it: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-accordion-menu-jquery/